# No download to Google Drive via C #

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

In the program, I need to make a download to Google Drive. I found an example on the Internet https://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/. I did everything following the example, but there was such a problem, the code works, no errors are produced, but on Google Drive itself no files appear.

```
public static Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File uploadFile(Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService _service, string _uploadFile, string _parent)
        {

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(_uploadFile))
            {
                Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
                body.Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_uploadFile);
                body.Description = "File uploaded by .NET";
                body.MimeType = GetMimeType(_uploadFile);
                body.Parents = new List<Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.ParentReference>() { new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.ParentReference() { Id = _parent } };

                // File's content.
                byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_uploadFile);
                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
                try
                {
                    Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = _service.Files.Insert(body, stream, GetMimeType(_uploadFile));
                    request.Upload();
                    return request.ResponseBody;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File does not exist: " + _uploadFile);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Found that part of the code `return request.ResponseBody;` 
returns Null, but why this happens I can not understand.

Comment: Since you're using the v2 Drive API version, I'd recommend you to check [Files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples) which you can apply to C#/.NET. There's a code sample on how to implement it. And, it's called 'uploading' not 'download to Google Drive'.